# Issues with installing pandas in python in MAC

Tags: python, macos, pandas

I am trying to install pandas in python. However, I am getting the following error. My numpy version is latest

```
In file included from pandas/index.c:317:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: In function ‘infer_type’:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:32: error: ‘PyDatetimeArrType_Type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:32: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:32: error: for each function it appears in.)
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: In function ‘get_datetime64_value’:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:53: error: ‘PyDatetimeScalarObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:53: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: In function ‘is_datetime64_object’:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:84: error: ‘PyDatetimeArrType_Type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: In function ‘is_timedelta64_object’:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:89: error: ‘PyTimedeltaArrType_Type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
In file included from pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:3,
                 from pandas/index.c:318:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_del_str’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:573: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_del_int32’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:574: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_del_int64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:575: warning: statement with no effect
In file included from pandas/index.c:318:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_del_float64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_del_pymap’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_del_pyset’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_del_strbox’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49: warning: statement with no effect
In file included from pandas/index.c:324:
pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.h: At top level:
pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.h:107: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘NPY_CASTING’
In file included from pandas/index.c:325:
pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.h:46: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘NPY_CASTING’
pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.h:84: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘NPY_CASTING’
pandas/index.c:643: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_t_5numpy_float16_t’
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6pandas_5index_get_value_at’:
pandas/index.c:2236: error: ‘NPY_DATETIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_5index_11IndexEngine_get_value’:
pandas/index.c:2738: error: ‘NPY_DATETIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_5index_convert_scalar’:
pandas/index.c:9735: error: ‘NPY_DATETIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_8datetime__cstring_to_dts’:
pandas/index.c:10542: error: ‘NPY_UNSAFE_CASTING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/index.c:10542: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘parse_iso_8601_datetime’ from incompatible pointer type
pandas/index.c:10542: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘parse_iso_8601_datetime’ from incompatible pointer type
pandas/index.c:10542: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘parse_iso_8601_datetime’ from incompatible pointer type
pandas/index.c:10542: error: too many arguments to function ‘parse_iso_8601_datetime’
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_8datetime__dts_to_pydatetime’:
pandas/index.c:10646: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
In file included from pandas/index.c:317:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: In function ‘infer_type’:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:32: error: ‘PyDatetimeArrType_Type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:32: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:32: error: for each function it appears in.)
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: In function ‘get_datetime64_value’:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:53: error: ‘PyDatetimeScalarObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:53: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: In function ‘is_datetime64_object’:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:84: error: ‘PyDatetimeArrType_Type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: In function ‘is_timedelta64_object’:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:89: error: ‘PyTimedeltaArrType_Type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
In file included from pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:3,
                 from pandas/index.c:318:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_resize_str’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:573: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:573: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:573: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_put_str’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:573: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:573: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_del_str’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:573: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_resize_int32’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:574: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:574: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:574: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_put_int32’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:574: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:574: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_del_int32’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:574: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_resize_int64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:575: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:575: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:575: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_put_int64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:575: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:575: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_del_int64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:575: warning: statement with no effect
In file included from pandas/index.c:318:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_get_float64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_resize_float64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_put_float64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_del_float64’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_get_pymap’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_resize_pymap’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_put_pymap’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_del_pymap’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_get_pyset’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_resize_pyset’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_put_pyset’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_del_pyset’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44: warning: statement with no effect
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_resize_strbox’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_put_strbox’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function ‘kh_del_strbox’:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49: warning: statement with no effect
In file included from pandas/index.c:324:
pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.h: At top level:
pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.h:107: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘NPY_CASTING’
In file included from pandas/index.c:325:
pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.h:46: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘NPY_CASTING’
pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.h:84: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘NPY_CASTING’
pandas/index.c:643: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_t_5numpy_float16_t’
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6pandas_5index_get_value_at’:
pandas/index.c:2236: error: ‘NPY_DATETIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_5index_11IndexEngine_get_value’:
pandas/index.c:2738: error: ‘NPY_DATETIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_5index_11IndexEngine__maybe_get_bool_indexer’:
pandas/index.c:4055: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6pandas_5index_11IndexEngine_16get_indexer_non_unique’:
pandas/index.c:5687: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/index.c:5791: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/index.c:5819: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_5index_11Int64Engine__maybe_get_bool_indexer’:
pandas/index.c:6847: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_5index_convert_scalar’:
pandas/index.c:9735: error: ‘NPY_DATETIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_8datetime__string_to_dts’:
pandas/index.c:10459: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_8datetime__cstring_to_dts’:
pandas/index.c:10542: error: ‘NPY_UNSAFE_CASTING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pandas/index.c:10542: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘parse_iso_8601_datetime’ from incompatible pointer type
pandas/index.c:10542: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘parse_iso_8601_datetime’ from incompatible pointer type
pandas/index.c:10542: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘parse_iso_8601_datetime’ from incompatible pointer type
pandas/index.c:10542: error: too many arguments to function ‘parse_iso_8601_datetime’
pandas/index.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_8datetime__dts_to_pydatetime’:
pandas/index.c:10646: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccfVLYMa.out (No such file or directory)
```

Any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: Did you get the dependencies installed?

Comment: Do you have the command line tools installed from XCode (latest version)?

Comment: @FelixZumstein. I have Xcode version 4.1

Comment: The latest version is 5.0. Can you update? But anyhow, I still guess you may not have the Command Line Tools installed: If you go to Xcode > Preferences > Downloads: Is there a Download Symbol for Command Line Tools (under Components) - If yes, install it